# Access input tag value in JSTL

Tags: jquery, jsp, jstl

I have an input tag and jquery code to assign value to that input. Now I want to use this value to loop using JSTL for each. How can I do it?

```
<input type="hidden" id="serviceCount" /> ==> Input tag in JSP file

$('#serviceCount').val(serviceCount++); ==>jquery to set value in JS file

<c:forEach begin="0" end="???" var="index"> ==>JSTL in JSP file.
```

Trying to put serviceCount value in end. I tried to put as ${serviceCount} but its not picking that value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it because `JSTL` is server-side code (which is running before `JQuery`) and `JQuery` is client-side code.

Comment: Yup I figure out that too. So instead of using JSTL to loop and create element I just used the jQuery to loop and create the element.

Comment: hi αƞjiβ, could you please explain more...